# How can I override the jetbrains jdk dependency required by idea-ultimate or idea-community in config.nix?

Tags: intellij-idea, package, overriding, nix

I’ve been setting up my local nix config as per nixpkgs manual's [declarative package management](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-declarative-package-management).

I’d like to include idea-ultimate as one of `myPackages`, but at this time the dependency idea has on the jetbrains jdk is [broken](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/75171), pointing to a non-existing package for macOS.

It’s trying to download `jbrsdk-11_0_2-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz` instead of `jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz`.

I was assuming I could fix that by overriding `jetbrainsjdk` as follows, but I’m getting: `error: attribute 'jetbrainsjdk' missing, at /Users/ldeck/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix:4:20` when I do anything like `nix-env -qa ‘jetbrains.*’`.

What is the right way to override idea-ultimate so that it uses the fixed jdk?

Here’s my `~./config/nixpkgs/config.nix`.

```
{
  allowUnfree = true;
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    jetbrainsjdk = pkgs.jetbrainsjdk.override {
      version = "520.11";
      src = pkgs.fetchurl {
        url = "https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b${jetbrainsjdk.version}.tar.gz";
        sha256 = "0d1qwbssc8ih62rlfxxxcn8i65cjgycdfy1dc1b902j46dqjkq9z";
      };
    };


    myProfile = pkgs.writeText "my-profile" ''
      export PATH=$HOME/.nix-profile/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
      export MANPATH=$HOME/.nix-profile/share/man:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/share/man:/usr/share/man
    '';
    myPackages = with pkgs; buildEnv {
      name = "my-packages";
      paths = [
        (runCommand "profile" {} ''
          mkdir -p $out/etc/profile.d
          cp ${myProfile} $out/etc/profile.d/my-profile.sh
        '')
    aspell
    bc
    coreutils
    direnv
    emacs
    emscripten
    ffmpeg
    gdb
    git
    hello
    jq
    nixops
    nox
    scala
    silver-searcher
      ];
      pathsToLink = [ "/share/man" "/share/doc" "/bin" "/etc" "/Applications" ];
      extraOutputsToInstall = [ "man" "doc" ];
    };
  };
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to @ChrisStryczynski who suggested I needed `with pkgs`, I’ve gotten a little further.

But now the problem is when attempting to install idea-ultimate with the custom jdk, it’s still requiring the broken, non-existing, `jbrsdk-11_02-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz.drv` from somewhere.

Updated config and logs below.

```
{
  allowUnfree = true;
  packageOverrides = pkgs: **with pkgs;** rec {

    myJetbrainsJdk = **pkgs.jetbrains.jdk.overrideAttrs** (oldAttrs: rec {
      version = "520.11";
      src = pkgs.fetchurl {
        url = "https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b520.11.tar.gz";
        sha256 = "0d1qwbssc8ih62rlfxxxcn8i65cjgycdfy1dc1b902j46dqjkq9z";
      };
    });

    myIdeaUltimate = pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate.override {
      jdk = myJetbrainsJdk;
    };

    ...

    myPackages = with pkgs; buildEnv {
    ...
    myIdeaUltimate
      ];
      ...
    };
  };
}
```

Logs

```sh
nix-channel --update; nix-env -iA nixpkgs.myPackages
unpacking channels...
replacing old 'my-packages'
installing 'my-packages'
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/9kfi3k9q6hi7z3lwann318hndbah535v-idea-ultimate.desktop.drv
  /nix/store/ica1m5yq3f3y05xnw7ln1lnfvp0yjvyf-download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b520.11.tar.gz.drv
  /nix/store/bf2hwhrvfl8g77gdiw053rayh06x0120-jetbrainsjdk-520.11.drv
  /nix/store/fazsa1a4l70s391rjk9yyi2hvrg0zbmp-download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_2-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz.drv
  /nix/store/fwwk976sd278zb68zy9wm5pkxss0rnhg-jetbrainsjdk-485.1.drv
  /nix/store/s3m2bpcyrnx9dcq4drh95882n0mk1d6m-ideaIU-2019.2.4-no-jbr.tar.gz.drv
  /nix/store/9kiajpmmsp3i6ysj4vdqq8dzi84mnr73-idea-ultimate-2019.2.4.drv
  /nix/store/jh1ixm54qinv8pk6kypvv6n6cfr4sws8-my-packages.drv
these paths will be fetched (0.02 MiB download, 0.12 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/hp90sbwznq1msv327f0lb27imvcvi80h-libnotify-0.7.8
building '/nix/store/9kfi3k9q6hi7z3lwann318hndbah535v-idea-ultimate.desktop.drv'...
copying path '/nix/store/hp90sbwznq1msv327f0lb27imvcvi80h-libnotify-0.7.8' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
building '/nix/store/fazsa1a4l70s391rjk9yyi2hvrg0zbmp-download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_2-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz.drv'...

trying https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_2-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: cannot download download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_2-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz from any mirror
builder for '/nix/store/fazsa1a4l70s391rjk9yyi2hvrg0zbmp-download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_2-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz.drv' failed with exit code 1
building '/nix/store/ica1m5yq3f3y05xnw7ln1lnfvp0yjvyf-download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b520.11.tar.gz.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/fwwk976sd278zb68zy9wm5pkxss0rnhg-jetbrainsjdk-485.1.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/9kiajpmmsp3i6ysj4vdqq8dzi84mnr73-idea-ultimate-2019.2.4.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/jh1ixm54qinv8pk6kypvv6n6cfr4sws8-my-packages.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/jh1ixm54qinv8pk6kypvv6n6cfr4sws8-my-packages.drv' failed
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this package uses the standalone JDK download instead of just downloading IntelliJ IDEA with the bundled JetBrains Runtime from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: Sure, but either way, would you happen to know the correct syntax for overriding / overloading it?

Comment: Not familiar with this package system, sorry.

Comment: Are you not missing a `with pkgs` (at line 2) which will 'import' all the attributes(?) under it, and bring it into scope?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski thanks, yes. That’s gotten me further. I’ll update the question based on the next problem.

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: with pkgs; rec {

    myJetbrainsJdk = pkgs.jetbrains.jdk.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
      version = “520.11”;
      src = pkgs.fetchurl {...};
      };
    });
    
    myIdeaUltimate = pkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate.override {
      jdk = myJetbrainsJdk;
    };
    
    ...
    
    myPackages = with pkgs; buildEnv {
      name = "my-packages";
      paths = [
 ...
 myIdeaUltimate
      ];
      ...
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [How do you discover the override attributes for a derivation](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-do-you-discover-the-override-attributes-for-a-derivation/5214), a solution has been found using an overlay.

```hs
# ~/config/nixpkgs/overlays/02-jetbrains.nix
self: super:
{
  jetbrains = super.jetbrains // {
    jdk = super.jetbrains.jdk.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
      version = "520.11";
      src = super.fetchurl {
        url = "https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jbr/download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b520.11.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "3fe1297133440a9056602d78d7987f9215139165bd7747b3303022a6f5e23834";
      };
      passthru = oldAttrs.passthru // {
        home = "${self.jetbrains.jdk}/Contents/Home";
      };
    });
    idea-ultimate = super.jetbrains.idea-ultimate.overrideAttrs (_: {
      name = "idea-ultimate.2019.2.4";
      src = super.fetchurl {
        url = "https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2019.2.4-no-jbr.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "09mz4dx3zbnqw0vh4iqr8sn2s8mvgr7zvn4k7kqivsiv8f79g90a";
      };
    });
  };
}
```

Install: `nix-env -iA 'nixpkgs.jetbrains.idea-ultimate'`.

Execute: `idea-ultimate`.

The crucial part of the puzzle was overriding the `passthru.home` variable to point to the overlayed JDK rather than the one required by super. Otherwise, you’ll be downloading the old JDK for runtime purposes.

```
passthru = oldAttrs.passthru // {
  home = "${self.jetbrains.jdk}/Contents/Home”;
};
```

Without `/Contents/Home` appended, idea won’t startup since `self.jetbrains.jdk` isn’t a valid home.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.myPackages
```

Just do:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.myIdeaUltimate
```

---

The problem being:

```
  myPackages = with pkgs; buildEnv {
    ...
    myIdeaUltimate
      ];
      ...
    };
```

Here you are still referencing the old `pkgs.myIdeaUltimate`.

Nixos seems to do some processing that replaces the `pkgs` with the appropriate from `packageOverrides`.

Comment: $ nix-env -iA nixos.myIdeaUltimate
error: attribute 'nixos' in selection path 'nixos.myIdeaUltimate' not found

Is that meant to be valid for non-daemon install on macOS?

Comment: Can you try `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.myIdeaUltimate`? I think it just refers to the channel name.

Comment: `installing 'idea-ultimate-2019.2.4’` these derivations will be built: `/nix/store/ica1m5yq3f3y05xnw7ln1lnfvp0yjvyf-download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b520.11.tar.gz.drv`, ..., `/nix/store/fazsa1a4l70s391rjk9yyi2hvrg0zbmp-download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_2-osx-x64-b485.1.tar.gz.drv`, ... `dependencies cannot be built`.

Comment: I believe the problem is in `myJetbrainsJdk = pkgs.jetbrains.jdk.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec { ... });` It appears that the `overrideAttrs` function performs the parent function first. Since the `src` of the parent fetches the non-existing jdk, it fails. How to override this is the question?

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you link a github gist with your full output?

Comment: Sure. https://gist.github.com/ldeck/e7b577a4b61972b99e9858ef0e2ca7a2

Comment: See also this discussion: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-do-you-discover-the-override-attributes-for-a-derivation/5214/2

Comment: Well, that shows you have a 404 for the link. Which you can replicate with curl? Is it not meant to be "https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jbr/download_file?file_path=jbrsdk-11_0_4-osx-x64-b520.11.tar.gz" instead?